# VC++ forms application centralized exception handling similar to C# forms application on .net platform

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, exception, centralized

I am new to VC++ and I have good experience in working with C# on .net platform.
Presently I am in a project which is a combination of VC++ and C# on .net platform.

I used to add centralized exception handling for all windows form applications developed using C#. What I mean by centralized exception here means something like this
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GlobalExceptionHandling.aspx

Now the problem is in my new project there is a legacy application which is in VC++. Changes have been made in the project so that it compiles in Visual Studio 2008 but the code is still unmanaged VC++. I see a lot of { try catch } in the present code and exceptions being handled locally without the application coming to know of the consequences.

I wanted to know if I can add centralized exception handling to this legacy VC++ forms application like I do for C# forms applications(using CurrentDomain_UnhandledException, etc). If yes where do I add this exception handling and how do I add it. A sample illustration would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the [`set_unexpected (<exception>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7twc8dwy%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Alternatively, you can use [`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634%28VS.85%29.aspx) function; which enables an application to supersede the top-level exception handler of each thread of a process.

> After calling this function, if an exception occurs in a process that is not being debugged, and the exception makes it to the unhandled exception filter, that filter will call the exception filter function specified by the lpTopLevelExceptionFilter parameter.